# How to change "n" behavior without losing the count like [4/15] in the statusbar

Tags: key-bindings

My goal is mapping `n` to `nzz` and keep the count on the status bar.

Based on **maparg** reference from [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_3)#maparg.28.29), I have tried this:

```
:exe 'nnoremap n nzz' . maparg('n', 'n')
```

It actually adds `zz`, changing the default behavior of the `n` key, but it makes me lose the count, let's say: [3/15] in the statusbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zz` will remove the count display (`[n/nn]`) in the statusbar if the view is changed. A quick and dirty solution to show the count again is to hit `n` or `N` again, ie.

```
nnoremap n nzzNn
```

**Edit**: If one would like to call additional functions, say `FlashCursorLine()`, insert that before `Nn`, as user Biggybi suggested in the comments, for example,

```
nnoremap n nzz:call FlashCursorLine()<CR>Nn
```

Comment: If I have a function to flash the cursor line, can I also add it? Would you have any idea about adding it on the map? The mentioned function is this: https://pastebin.com/q355Mbmh

Comment: @SergioAraujo you should only need to append `:call FlashCursorLine()<cr>` to your mapping (or maybe put that right before `Nn`).

Comment: I have updated the mentioned pastebin code for those who would like to test this approach: Each 'n' moves the cursor to the center of screen and flashes the cursorline.